# Automate File transfer from Unix Server to Windows Server using WINSCP

Tags: shell, automation, winscp

I need support to automate File transfer from Unix Server to Windows Server using WINSCP.

WinSCP is installed on Windows server, therefore I want to schedule file transfer at every 30 minutes intervals.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP is a client for transfer file using sftp, ftp or ssh. If you want to the Windows server, You must set up a ssh or ftp server in the Windows Server.

### Install SSH Server

You can refer this link to [install SSH Server in Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#installing_sftp_ssh_server).

### Schedulling The Job

For the file transfer, you can use `scp` command and schedule it using crontab. The content of the crontab schedule will be like below.

```
*/30 * * * * scp /path/to/your/file  user@hostDestination:/c/temp
```